# Proof of the Well Ordering Principle for $\Bbb N$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction, well-orders

Working on proving the well ordering principle, I ran into this way to do it and I was hoping someone might read through it and tell me if I have any holes. I've looked over it a few times but I want to be sure.

> **Theorem** — Each non-empty subset $S$ of $\Bbb N$ contains a smallest element.
>
> **Proof** — Suppose that $S$ has no smallest element and define $T = \Bbb N \setminus S$. Suppose $\{1, 2, 3, ..., n\} \subset T$ and $n \in \Bbb N$. Further, suppose $\{1, 2, 3, ... , n\} \subset T \Rightarrow n + 1 \in T$. Then $n + 1 \notin S$ because it would be a least element of S. Since $1 \in T$ and $n + 1 \in T, T = \Bbb N$ by the induction axiom.
>
> Since $T = \Bbb N \setminus S = \Bbb N, S = \varnothing$, which contradicts that $S$ is non-empty. Thus, each non-empty subset $S$ of $\Bbb N$ contains a smallest element. $\Box$

The only thing I can think of that might ruin my argument is supposing that $\{1, 2, 3, ... , n\} \subset T \Rightarrow n + 1 \in T$. I'm essentially saying that because induction works, the proof works.

But then again, this really shouldn't be a problem since the proof rests on the assumption that $S$ has no smallest element and therefore should maintain that property regardless of any subset of $\Bbb N$, including a set as fussily defined as $T$. Right?

Comment: Do you mean $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}\subset T$? Or are you using the definition $n+1=n\cup \{n\}$?

Comment: Whoops, yes, I'll fix that.

Comment: >I'm essentially saying that because induction works, the proof works. $$~\\~$$
IMO, this will be a circular proof because the proof for the principle of mathematical induction uses the fact that $\Bbb N$ is well-ordered.

Comment: You are fine. Principle of Induction implies WOP and vice versa. You need one to prove the other.

Comment: @Tciur See I thought about that too because to prove that induction works you have to assume the WOP.

Comment: The proof of the well-ordering principle (or of the induction principle, which are equivalent - when you take induction to mean so called "strong induction") depends on your definition of $\mathbb{N}$. Defining it as $\omega$, the smallest infinite ordinal makes it trivial. Defining it as the smallest inductive set (see some ways the axiom of infinity is stated) makes it more interesting. In this second context you can prove the induction principle and from it deduce the well-ordering principle. However, the problem with the presented proof is its presentation, not the idea

Comment: @Max Could you elaborate on the presentation bit? How would you change it?

Comment: You say "Further suppose $\{1,...,n\} \subset T \implies n+1\in T$", whereas what you're doing is assuming that $\{1,...,n\}\subset T$ and deducing that $n+1\in S$, you're not assuming that the implication holds (otherwise the proof lacks a big step). Moreover since you're not at a too advanced level -it seems- you might want to prove that $1\in T$ (even if it's obvious)

Comment: @Max Nope, not very advanced just yet. Working on it! Thanks for your response, but I'm confused by it. I'm saying suppose that $\{1, . . . , n\} \subset T$ implies that $\{n+1\} \in T$ and so $n+1 \notin S$, not deducing that $n+1 \in S$. I need $S$ to be empty to show $T=\Bbb N$. So if I'm understanding you correctly, I should first prove that $1 \in T$ and then, using the induction axiom, show that $T= \Bbb N$ by proving $n+1 \in T$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$, then $S = \varnothing$ and everything is glitter and rainbows. Would that make more sense?